# How can I stop a Java Thread from another one?

Tags: java, multithreading

Maybe I'm thinking to complicated, but I have the following situation:

I have a class Server.java extending Thread with the following relevant part of the code:

```
public void run() {
    while(listening) {
        try {
            ServerThread cst = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
            cst.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            listening = false;
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My ServerThread then handles all the incoming stuff.

My question now is, if there is any possibility to stop this Thread (Server) like for example over the command line.

I tried to add a new class, that would handle command line input and .interrupt() this Thread, but that kinda just made a big mess..

Comment: If you have your main thread spinning off subthreads, then you have a reference to said thread, no?

Comment: With *recent* Java versions (I think with 1.5, but I'm unsure), direct thread operations have been deprecated / removed; threads should instead cooperate, i.e. signal each other to end - like others are already telling you.

Comment: Q: What would happen if a different thread called `serverSocket.close()` while your server thread was waiting in `serverSocket.accept()`?  (I don't know the answer, because I don't do a lot of network programming, but I know how I could test it to find out.)

Comment: i don't do much network programming either but it sounds like the OP needs to close the socket, see http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html.  Calling interrupt will not help unless piped streams are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

1. Provide a setter for `listening` that can be accessed from another class/thread.
2. Set a reasonable timeout (say, 1 sec) on the `ServerSocket` and handle the `SocketTimeoutException`.

To stop the thread, set `listening` to `false` and within 1 second the thread will stop.  If you want finer control, investigate the async I/O classes in `java.nio`.

Comment: The Exception is not quite the fanciest way to solve this, but it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can define listening  as `volatile`, with a **setter** and set that to `false` from another class whenever you want to stop the Thread.

Comment: This doesn't deal with the fact that the `accept()` blocks uninterruptibly.  If no connections are being established this won't work.